# Nodejs React CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, cors

i have got this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/uploadAvatar' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

when my server cors options are:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET");
      return res.status(200).json({});
  } 
  next();
});
```

And from the frontend i'm calling the server with this options:

```
var data = {
      image: imageCrop.current.getImage().toDataURL(),
      target: targetImage,
    }
    var config = {
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
        setUploadPercent(percentCompleted)
      },
      headers: authHeader(),
      withCredentials: true,
    }
    axios.post('uploadAvatar', data ,config).then((res) => {
      setUploadPercent(0);
      if (res.status === 200) {
        cogoToast.success("upload is completed")
        setUploadModal(false);
        upDateuserInfo();
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      setUploadPercent(0);
      setUploadModal(false);
    });
```

The Auth header service is provided with:

```
export default function authHeader() {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

  if (user && user.accessToken) {
    // For Spring Boot back-end
    // return { Authorization: "Bearer " + user.accessToken };
    // for Node.js Express back-end
    return { Authorization: "Bearer " + user.accessToken};
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?? please help me!!! p.s. the call is working if i remove the image parameter and I can't set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*" because it will give me an erro on using the wildcard.

Comment: For security reasons, front-end webpages are not allowed to make requests to servers other than the one they come from. This is called CORS. To my understanding, you are making a request from a front-end page supplied by localhost:8081 to localhost:3000 (which are two separate servers according to your browser), so this comes into play. What you should do instead is make the request from your front-end to its back-end at localhost:8081, then have the back-end of localhost:8081 make a request to localhost:3000.

Comment: @fin444 thank you for your reply, but how can I forward the calls from back-end localhost:8081, to localhost:3000 with React?

Comment: Can you upload your project to somewhere like Github and link it? I am having trouble fully understanding how your client and server interact.

Comment: thank you @fin444 for you suggestion, i have made it putting a proxy on React side! thank you very much